# react-route,react-hot-loader.webpack (You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

it's my first project that use `react`,`react-router`,`react-hot-loader`,`webpack-dev-server` and `webpack`. when I change the code in react component, the hot-loader become effective, but at the same time, the console tell me a warning:

> You cannot change 《Router routes》; it will be ignored.

I don't know how to solve this issue.there is code:

webpack code:

```
    var path = require('path');
    var webpack = require('webpack');

    module.exports = {
      devtool: 'source-map' ,
      entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './jsx/index'
      ],
      output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/public/'
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
      ],
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', 'json']
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [{
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,   
          loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
          }]
      },
      watch:true
    };
```

index code:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom'
    import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'
    import App from './index/app'
    import About from './index/about'
    import Inbox from './index/inbox'
    class Routers extends React.Component {
      render() {
         return ( 
            <Router>
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                  <Route path="about" component={About} />
                  <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
          );
        }
    }

ReactDOM.render(<Routers />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

thank you !!!!

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2704... Quite a few people have raised this and there are a few things you can try based on the suggestions there

Comment: Try defining routes in a constant to see if it works. I use a similar setup in my project and I haven't seen this error message.

Comment: @AbhishekJain.thank for your answer,I have been watched github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2704.but i can't find the solution from it.i don't know if the warning  will have effect on my project ,even if the react-router and hot-loader is useful.

Comment: @AbhishekJain. oh my god.i have been defined routes in a constant yesterday,maybe i have writed something wrong,it's not useful. but just now,i use the way again, it's efficient.
thank you very much ! ahhh...

Comment: Cool... Happy to help!!

Comment: There's a solution available here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37533533/58961

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Hot loader 3 with webpack-dev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466598/react-hot-loader-3-with-webpack-dev)

Answer (score 10):

Only thing you need to do, it's to throw `<Route />` out of render() method.
So, there are many ways to solve this issue.
Most Official way is what @Stormy say.
My solution like this:

```
const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} />
  </Route>
)

// Don't let <Route> in render() method
class Routers extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return ( 
        <Router>
          { routes }
        </Router>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this solution. Why does this happen anyway? My code works just fine even with the warning, but it's annoying to have any type of errors in console.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this configuration
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2704#issuecomment-170940448

```
  const routeConfig = [
  { path: '/:locale',
    component: App,
    indexRoute: { component: NewsCardsContainer },
    ...
  }
];
return (
  <IntlProvider key="intl" {...intlData}>
    <Router history={history} routes={routeConfig} />
  </IntlProvider>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Stormy's suggestion of using `<Router routes={Routes}/>` worked for me. Here are my warning free code snippits with react hot module replacement:

**./index.js**

```
import './globals';
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { AppContainer as HotContainer } from "react-hot-loader";
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Routes from "./components/Routes.jsx";

const render = function() {
    let Router = require('react-router').Router;
    ReactDOM.render(
        <HotContainer>
            <Router history={browserHistory} routes={Routes}/>
        </HotContainer>,
        document.getElementById('react-container'),
    );
};

render();

if( module.hot ) {
    module.hot.accept('./components/Routes', () => {
        render();
    });
}
```

**./components/Routes.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, IndexRoute } from "react-router";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import Graphs from "./graphs/Graphs.jsx";
import Trends from "./trends/Trends.jsx";
import Patterns from "./patterns/Patterns.jsx";

const Routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Graphs}/>
        <Route path="graphs" component={Graphs}/>
        <Route path="trends" component={Trends}/>
        <Route path="patterns" component={Patterns}/>
    </Route>
);
export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

The router actually should never change, so you should be able to just return false for shouldComponentUpdate() in this case.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'
import App from './index/app'
import About from './index/about'
import Inbox from './index/inbox'
class Routers extends React.Component {

  shouldComponentUpdate(){
     return false;
  }

  render() {
     return ( 
        <Router>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
              <Route path="about" component={About} />
              <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is change "Reflux.Component" to "React.Component"

```js
class AppRouter extends Reflux.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.store = AuthStore;
  }
  requireAuth (nextState, replace, callback) {

    if (nextState.location.pathname != '/login' && nextState.location.pathname != '/logout') {
      ActionsAuth.jwt.refresh();
    }
    const token = UtilsJWT().getToken();
    if (token){
      if (nextState.location.pathname == '/login') {

        window.location.href = '/main';
      }
      callback();
    }else{
      if (nextState.location.pathname != '/login') {
      window.location.href = '/login';
      }
    }
  }
  verifyAuth (nextState, replace, callback) {
    const token = UtilsJWT().getToken();
    if (token){
      if (nextState.location.pathname == '/login') {

        window.location.href = '/main';
      }
      callback();
    }else{
      if (nextState.location.pathname != '/login') {
        window.location.href = '/login';
      }
      callback();
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route path="/" component={App}>
              <IndexRoute component={Login} onEnter={ this.verifyAuth }/>
              <Route path="login" component={Login} onEnter={ this.verifyAuth }/>
              <Route path="main" component={Main} onEnter={ this.requireAuth }/>
              <Route path="logout" component={Logout} onEnter={ this.requireAuth }/>
              <Route path="local-sync" component={LocalSync} onEnter={ this.requireAuth }/>
              <Route path="*" component={Login} onEnter={ this.verifyAuth }/>
          </Route>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue，my Solution is change "import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'" to "import {HashRouter, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'"
my code:

```js
ReactDOM.render((
    <HashRouter>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
            </ul>
            <hr/>

            <Route path="/" exact component={createComponent(Home)}/>
            <Route path="/login" component={createComponent(Login)}/>
        </div>
    </HashRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but someone might find this useful. I tried a lot of stuff and what finally worked for me is:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'
import App from './index/app'
import About from './index/about'
import Inbox from './index/inbox'

class Routers extends React.Component {
   private routes = (
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <Route path="about" component={About} />
          <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} />
      </Route>
   );

   render() {
      return ( 
         <Router>
            {this.routes}
         </Router>
       );
    }
}
```