# Dispatching action in redux gives error '[react-router] You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm using reactjs, react-router & redux in my application. I'm using async actions, following is my action.js code

```
  signUser(state,user) {
    return function (dispatch){
      return dispatch(requestSignUp());
    }
  }


export default function requestSignUp(){
 return {
   type: Actions.REQUEST,
   signUserReducer:{
    action: Actions.REQUEST
   }
  }
 }
```

Following is my store.js code

```
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
let finalState = compose(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger()))(createStore)

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return finalState(reducer, initialState);
}
```

Following is my reducer.js code

```
export default function signUserReducer(state = initialState, action) {

if (typeof state == 'undefined') {
    return state;
}

switch (action.type) {

    case Actions.REQUEST:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            action: action.signUserReducer.action
        });
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

Now whenever I'm dispatching an action an error displays on my browser console stating

> Warning: [react-router] You cannot change 'Router routes'; it will be ignored

I tried solving this with 'react-router-redux', but it's not solving.

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where you define your routes? The issue is most likely there.

Comment: @AbhishekJain: render() {
    const { store, history } = this.props
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history} >

              <Route path="/" dispatch={this.props.dispatch} response={this.props.signUserReducer}  component={SignIn}/>
              <Route path="sign-up" component={SignUp}/>

        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }

Comment: @AbhishekJain I've implemented react-redux-router but still whenever I pass action to dispatch it gives the same error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760825/react-route-react-hot-loader-webpack-you-cannot-change-router-routes-it-will See if this helps. This is a common problem with react-router.

Comment: @AbhishekJain:How to pass props to this constant routes..

Comment: @AbhishekJainThanks for the help, by making routes constant it worked, along with it I connected my each container with the provider and it worked.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

here is the answer from the Redux creator, he left on [github](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1586), I think, it makes a lot of sense

> A good first step would be to look again into the error message. It’s
>   not a random error; it actually tells what happened. It says that
>   `Router` component cannot accept new value of `routes` prop. This means
>   you are recreating new routes every time you render the root
>   component, rather than create them once for the lifetime of your app,
>   which is the scenario React Router intends to support. The conclusion
>   is you would need to look into where you render the Router component,
>   and **make sure you don't create routes on every render**.

Comment: So how do we fix this :/

Comment: @JamieHutber  make `const routes` constant outside the render and include like `{routes}`, see the comments above

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me :D Oddly I have done this already, it must be something else in the way I am setting up. I will continue to dig

Comment: yes, this helped me in my app, @DennisDecoene share your code if you need a hand

Comment: @vitr, I have openend another question, related to this with link to the code, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995841/where-do-i-update-the-location-after-an-async-dispatch-with-react-router-and-red